# Why am I getting "Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)..."?

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js

I'm having this problem `Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.`
 when I try to import a icon from React-Icons in my NextJs app.

See my code below.

```
import React from "react";

import MdPlayCircleOutline from "react-icons";

const Podcast = props => {
  return (
    <div className="podcast">
      <div className="podcastName">
        <h4>{props.title}</h4>
      </div>

      <MdPlayCircleOutline />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Podcast;
```

Why this?

Comment: Can you try importing like this: import {MdPlayCircleOutline} from "react-icons"

Comment: Yes, I've tried but not work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each icon set has their own folder. For Material Design icons, it is `'./md'`. So, the import should be:

```js
import { MdPlayCircleOutline } from 'react-icons/md'
```

See: http://react-icons.github.io/react-icons/#usage

Comment: Wow, I had not noticed that. Thanks you very much bro!